# Handle child component update of changing column count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently experiencing a lake of knowledge about Reactjs.  I have a component that is composed of columns. The number of column is variable (the user can change it). In this column there are some items that contains youtube embed video. 

When I change the number of column the parent element is refreshing and the child components are updating: the video player is refreshed (so the video is paused and is seek to 0s).

I would like to have a system that be able to keep my child unupdated when I change the column count.

I supposed, when I am changing my column count, React reuse some childs component available and change their props by other child component. Because sometimes the video don't break.

> child component

```
export default class Article extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        visible: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        link: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        userId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        contentId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        typeId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        typeName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        username: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        description: React.PropTypes.string,
        imageUrl: React.PropTypes.string
    };

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.link !== this.props.link;
    }

    render() { ... }

}
```

> parent component

```
class Home extends UserComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    mode: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    columnCount: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    userList: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  state = {
    contents: [],
    columnCount: 0,
    userList: [],
  }

  ...

  renderArticles = (columnCount, columnNumber) => {
    if (this.state.contents.length > 0)
      return this.state.contents.map((content, key) => {
        if ((key + columnNumber) % columnCount !== 0) return null;
        let username = 'unknown';
        let typeName = 'unknown';

        this.state.userList.forEach((user) => {
          if (user.userId === content.userId) username = user.username;
        })

        const types = Type.getTypes();
        if (types) {
          types.forEach((type) => {
            if (content.typeId === type.id) typeName = type.name;
          })
        }
        return (
          <Article
            key={content.id}
            visible={true}
            title={content.title}
            link={content.link}
            userId={content.userId}
            typeId={content.typeId}
            contentId={content.id}
            date={content.date}
            description={content.description}
            imageUrl={content.imageUrl}
            username={username}
            typeName={typeName}
          />
        );
      });
    else
      return null;
  }

  render() {
    const { columnCount } = this.props.columnCount === 0 ? this.state : this.props;
    const containers = [];
    var i = 0;
    do {
      containers.push(
        <div key={i} className={styles.containers}>
          {this.renderArticles(columnCount, i)}
        </div>
      );
      i++;
    } while (i < columnCount);

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {containers}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    columnCount: state.articleColumnFilter.columnCount
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(articleColumnActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Does `shouldComponentUpdate` ever gets fired ?

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal On some childs, yes. I have given up this functionnality and I have put the video player into a popup (like the youtube android application).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, key={content.id}  is keep changing for the same column you previously rendered. Key need to be unique within the parent and should not change for the same item which you previously rendered.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

renderArticles = (columnCount, columnNumber) => {

```
    return (
      <Article
        key={content.id}
        ...
        contentId={content.id}
        ...
      />
    );
  });
else
  return null;
```

}